# How can I tell whether or not I am in a text area?

Tags: scripting, x11, window-manager, cursor

I am running a Window Manager and am soon getting a Thinkpad x220 tablet. I was hoping to make the tablet a little more functional by having an on-screen keyboard, and I have set it up so I can show/hide the keyboard and have it work. However, because I am not running GNOME I can't use the auto-hide function.

My question is, how can I determine, through a bash-script; python; etc, whether or not I have a text area focused, so that I can create a daemon to automatically show and hide the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

X11 itself does not know where the text areas are on the screen - but modern applications, especially those using the Qt or GTK toolkits, provide ways for programs to query this to allow for accessibility helpers such as screen readers for visually impaired users or on-screen keyboards for those who can't use a physical keyboard, using [AT-SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_Technology_Service_Provider_Interface), and you should be able to do the same via the [pyatspi2 Python module](https://git.gnome.org/browse/pyatspi2/tree/README).